# NGINX performance with large number of server blocks

Tags: nginx

I can't find much helpful information on whether or not having a large number of server blocks (roughly 8k-10k) will noticeably slow NGINX down. Our clients have anywhere from 1 to several hundred subdomains, and we are looking into having client specific server blocks in either a single large config file, or many individual ones which will specify the client's URL's as server_names.

The reason for wanting to do this is to allow for client-specific zone monitoring with NGINX Plus, opposed to having one large zone that everyone falls under and having lump metrics.

Or is there a better way to do this of which I am not yet aware?

Comment: [Related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/620210/what-determines-a-practical-limit-on-the-number-of-server-blocks-in-nginx-config).

Comment: Did you thought about running a benchmark and compare the options to be sure?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to see if anyone else had actually tried this and what kind of results they saw.